# C# Trying to figure out how to incorporate negative values into my code

Tags: c#

I am currently coding a small console game for an assignment. There are two warriors and they have properties they use that influence their fight. Here is an example of a game:

**Warriors:**

Angrif -- Strength 12, Dexterity 12, HitPoints 10, Armor 2
Hector -- Strength 10, Dexterity 18, HitPoints 12, Armor 1

**Round 1:**

Hector attacks Angriff and hits.  Hector does 5 points of damage minus Angrif's 2 points of armor.  Angrif has 7 HitPoints remaining.
Angrif attacks Hector and misses.

**Round 2:**

Angrif attacks Hector and hits.  Angrif does 2 points of damage minus Hectors' 1 point of Armor.  Hector has 11 HitPoints remaining.
Hector attacks Angrif and hits.  Hector does 6 points of damange minus Angrif's 2 points of Armor.  Angrif has 3 HitPoints remaining.

**Round 3:**

Hector attacks Angrif and hits.  Hector does 3 points of damage minus Angrif's 2 points of Armor.  Angrif has 2 HitPoints remaining.
Angrif attacks Hector and hits.  Angrif does 5 points of damage minus Hector's 1 point of Armor.  Hector has 7 HitPoints remaining.

**Round 4:**

Hector attacks Angrif and hits.  Hector does 6 points of damage minus Angrif's 2 points of Armor.  Angrif is killed.

The fight is over and Hector has defeated Angriff.

Now, one of the warnings my intructor gives is

> "Make sure that your damage can't be a negative value that actually
>   increases the struck Warrior's HitPoints."

I am very confused and my mind is just blank when I tried to incorporate this into my code. I get the concept of the rule (or endless loop) but I don't know how to have it in my code. I will include a snippet of my battle method. In the code, the main two things to be looking at is the first line and third line, as that is where this subtraction occurs. If you guys need more of my code, I will provide it.

```
if (warriorOne.HitPoints > (currentDamage - warriorOne.Armor))
{
   warriorOne.HitPoints = warriorOne.HitPoints - 
       (currentDamage - warriorOne.Armor);

   if (currentDamage == 1 & warriorOne.Armor == 1)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(warriorTwo.Name + " does 1 point of damage minus " + 
           warriorOne.Name + "'s 1 point of Armor. " + 
           warriorOne.Name + " has " + warriorOne.HitPoints + 
           " HitPoints remaining.");
   }
   else if (currentDamage == 1)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(warriorTwo.Name + " does 1 point of damage minus " + 
           warriorOne.Name + "'s " + warriorOne.Armor + " points of Armor. " + 
           warriorOne.Name + " has " + warriorOne.HitPoints + 
           " HitPoints remaining.");
   }
   else if (warriorOne.Armor == 1)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(warriorTwo.Name + " does " + currentDamage + 
            " points of damage minus " + warriorOne.Name + 
            "'s 1 point of Armor. " + warriorOne.Name + " has " + 
            warriorOne.HitPoints + " HitPoints remaining.");
   }
   else
   {
        Console.WriteLine(warriorTwo.Name + " does " + currentDamage + 
            " points of damage minus " + warriorOne.Name + "'s " + 
            warriorOne.Armor + " points of Armor. " + 
            warriorOne.Name + " has " + warriorOne.HitPoints + 
            " HitPoints remaining.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Math.Max` might be helpful (you pass it 2 numbers, it gives you this largest. If you pass 0 and -5, you'll get 0).

Comment: Please try to shorten your question down to the specific issue. Most people will not want to read a whole description of a game that's not really relevant to the question at hand, and will just pass this by.

Comment: Same thing with the code. So much of that code is just console output and not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that this hint points to lies with the following line of code

```
warriorOne.HitPoints = warriorOne.HitPoints - (currentDamage - warriorOne.Armor);
```

In case `warriorOne.Armor` is greater than `currentDamage` the outcome would be that warriorOne is *healed*. That's where @John's hint with `Math.Max` comes in.

The calculated damage must be limited to a minimum of zero by doing

```
warriorOne.HitPoints = warriorOne.HitPoints - Math.Max(0, currentDamage - warriorOne.Armor);
```